# Invoke DB2 encrypt function in Active Record in Ruby on Rails for new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, db2

I want to encrypt a value using the IBM DB2 `encrypt` built-in function. I am using the below code for saving a record.

`````
````
user = User.new 
user.password = "encrypt('mysecurepassword')" 
user.save
````
`````

Active Record is saving the password as a string and I am unable to call the DB2 `encrypt` function.

Comment: why would you expect something else from a string?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I need that string to be execute on database.

Comment: Please note that this function is deprecated and might disapear in a future version http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004211.html